# What is the intent to launch Factory reset settings page in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-settings

The following code launches the system settings app page. From there, I would have to navigate sub pages to get to Factory reset options.

```
fun displaySettings() {
    startActivity(getIntent())
    finish()
}

private fun getIntent(): Intent {
    return Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS)
}
```

I have a requirement to add a button and onClick would take the user to factory reset page.

In the [android settings page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings), I see actions for various settings pages. Not sure which one launches factory reset intent.

I was wondering if there is an intent to launch factory reset options page directly.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm looking for the same thing.